# How to redirect when loading a FormView?

Tags: django, redirect

Using the class based view `FormView` I want to redirect to a different page if a user is already activated.

So I've tried overriding the `get_form_kwargs` function:

```
class UserActivateView(AnonymousRequiredMixin, FormView):
    ...
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        ....
        if profile.activated:
                # User is already activated an can log in
                messages.info(
                    self.request,
                    'You are already activated. '
                    'Login or click forgot password if you have forgotten'
                )
                redirect(to=reverse_lazy('auth_login'))
        ....
        return kwargs
```

Using this method the message is added but the redirect is never done.

Am I doing this redirect at the correct place, I've been using [ccbv](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/) as a reference

Comment: No, you are not. `get_form_kwargs` is for, well, getting the form kwargs. This should be done in the methods that are responsible for returning the response, ie `dispatch`, or `get` and `post`. Note, you also need to actually return the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use [user_passes_test() decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) and decorate the `dispatch()` method of your CBV

Or just override `dispatch()` method so you can include your message

Comment: The `user_passes_test` redirects to login so will try for the dispatch override instead

Comment: `user_passes_test` takes an optional `login_url` argument, so you don't have to redirect to the login page.

Comment: @surfer190, was it helpful the answer? did you manage to redirect successfully from there?